# WebRequest with Proxy to whatsmyip.net shows my real ip

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to proxy my requests, but it seems that the proxy setting is ignored.
I'm using the following code:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://whatsmyip.net/");
req.Proxy = new WebProxy("195.128.253.243", 8080) { BypassProxyOnLocal = false };
req.CachePolicy = new RequestCachePolicy(RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
var html = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

The proxy is just a random free proxy from [here](http://www.freeproxylists.net/).
The result always contains my real ip instead of the proxy ip.

When I'm surfing to that website using [hidemyass](http://www.hidemyass.com/) or other alternatives, the ip changes as expected.

Anyone has an idea for what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for leaving that code here. This was the only example I found that showed how to do this.

Comment: @jp2code There are literally hundreds of examples for that. But sure, glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried your code (without the HttpWebRequest cast) bouncing off my local tor server and it works as expected. Have you tried the proxy directly within IE?

Comment: It seems that the services somehow increase anonymity of proxies. With a secured proxy it worked just as expected, which is enough for me.